# Automatically adjust large plots to fit page pdf output from rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am having issues when knitting my rmarkdown file to PDF with large plots. The plots get cut when producing the PDF file.

The problem is that I can't find a way to automatically adjust the height and width of all the plots. As I am writing a very large report, I have several plots like this, thus adjusting them separately (through fig.width and fig.height) is out of question.

Is there any package/command that I should use in my YAML or preamble.tex file?

Minimal reproducible example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

## Large Plot

```{r}
library(meta)

data(Fleiss93)

##
m <- metabin(event.e, n.e, event.c, n.c,
              data = Fleiss93, studlab = study,
              sm = "RR", method = "I")

forest(m)
```
````

Answer (score 7):

To change default settings, put the following code chunk early in your document:

````
```{r include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height = 9, fig.width = 7)
```
````

You can also use something like

````
```{r include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.height = "\\textheight",  out.width = "\\textwidth")
```
````

to rescale the images to try to exactly fill the page.  By default `knitr` will prevent you from changing the aspect ratio, but if you really want to fill the page, distortion and all, use

````
```{r include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.height = "\\textheight",  out.width = "\\textwidth",
                      out.extra = "keepaspectratio=false")
```
````

I'd recommend against that final choice; your plots will look really ugly.

And more generally:  the `knitr` defaults are pretty good.  Every one that you change using `knitr::opts_chunk$set()` will need to be specified explicitly when you want the original default.  So for weird options like these, it's probably not out of the question to just cut and paste the options into each chunk that needs them, and leave the defaults alone.

Comment: I have already tried setting it to "\\textheight" and "\\textwidth", but for some reason it doesn't work... Also, the first option to set fig.height and fig.width is quite nice, but the problem is that almost all the graphs differ in height and width.. so it doesn't work actually for my purpose. I wonder if there is a way to tell Pandoc to adjust the plots to the maximum height and width possible without cutting them?

Comment: Pandoc isn't involved.  R sets the height and width of the originals, and LaTeX sets the rescaling.  LaTeX can rescale to full size (using \\textwidth or \\maxwidth), but it will look bad unless the original sizing done by R had the same aspect ratio, and R doesn't know what aspect ratio LaTeX will use.  So there's nothing better than trial and error.